# How to fill large stubbed pojo with test and actual values?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

While writing junits for a analytics calculator I realised that in order to test a simple functionality I have manually create stubbed pojo's with test values, which is taking more time for writing actual business logic ?
For example if I want to check a function which calculates sum `( person.age ) / count (person)`
Now while writing the java junits I mocked the service which returns a collection of person objects and then manually created 3 person objects each having some age .

Now if the person class is huge say **30-40 fields** . is there an easy way to create such objects ? Like pull data from db and create objects on the fly by parsing a CSV file taken from db ?

I want to know what are the recommended ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one basic thing about Unittests is, that they should be fast. If a unittest takes too long, people will stop executing it. For this reason (and the danger of errors outside the unittest's control, like the database being down), I would not suggest to store the values in a database.

But your case does not sound as if you actually NEED 30-40 fields to be filled, do you? Why does your class need all of them? And if you do, do these fields to be actually meaningfull or could you fill them with random data? Or could every person have the same data except for the stuff you want to test?

Personally, I would prefer not to access a file or something like this to test something that has nothing to do with file handling, so I would search for a way to limit the things the test has to do (a test should also be easy, if it's enormously long, nobody understands it). If I had to, I would chose a file over a database (simply because a file can be stored in the test resources and is at least less problematic than a database). But still, the best way would probably not to need a file or a database.

Comment: Yes , I do need close to 40 fields. They will be used to test various analytics that I am going to write . Like Person.name , age , salary , zip code will be used to generate analytics of distribution of age across geography

Comment: Sounds a little bit like your "unit" is very big. Any chance to seperate it into smaller methods that can be tested with less data?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to separate the 40 fields in logical groups and test the logic separately for each group.
This means:

- create pojos filling fields belonging to first group
- test the logic
- create pojos filling fields for the second group

And so on.

Better could be to have sub-pojos, each with fields from one group, to be tested separately and independently.
For example Person could have an Address instance, a Work instance...., all tested by their own.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise strongly against pulling data from the database on the fly: That could easily make your tests nondeterministic (i.e. able to be broken if the data changes), and undetected/untested errors in the test itself may render your average test useless. Also, if you create "representative results" from the database offline (and then, for instance, check them in) you may have to be especially careful to randomize the fields chosen and avoid saving sensitive or personal information in a leakable way.

---

It's not too surprising that writing tests may take longer than writing the system under test, and that's not *necessarily* an indication that something is wrong—especially for mission-critical code. That said, you can usually optimize tests in similar ways to optimizing code.

Depending on whether your model objects are mutable, you may want to consider a *testing helper library* that creates a Person or PersonBuilder class with *randomized starting values taken from a deterministic seed*. At that point, your test might look like this:

```
@Test public void testMeanAge() {
  // Each person will have a name like "iuwaqeiouzzsxdfv", and a
  // randomized age from 18 to 80 (for instance), and so on
  Person person1 = PersonBuilder.random().withAge(25).build();
  Person person2 = PersonBuilder.random().withAge(28).build();
  Person person3 = PersonBuilder.random().withAge(28).build();
  when(yourService.getPeople())
      .thenReturn(new Person[] { person1, person2, person3 });
  assertEquals(27, yourPerson.getMeanAge());
}
```

Creating the test builder will be somewhat verbose and not all that interesting, and you'll need to be somewhat familar with real potential values as far as your tests are concerned, but with something like this you can create a fake Person very easily—which might come in handy in other tests across your codebase.